# How to retrieve an hyperlink from an email, and go and visit it?

Tags: python, email, hyperlink, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get to this python code working that would retrieve my email from `imap.laposte.net` (from France, where I am from and where I live), then follow a link given in the mail, and then send back to the email address one of the indicated pages.
 The first part of the job is already okay; I found several examples about using `imaplib` on the net, to retrieve and select what I want; and I'm confident that it will also be easy to learn how to send the page I will have visited.
 But the problem is there, given a link within an email, how can I select it, and go and visit the given page?
 I retrieved the email as a kind of string, in `data[0].split()`, and I work on that string with Beautiful Soup as if it was à web page, in order to extract from it the url's contained within the email :

```
import imaplib, rfc822, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
server  ='imap.laposte.net'
username='username'
password='VeryStrong'
M = imaplib.IMAP4(server)
M.login(username, password)
M.select()
typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    pos1=data[0][1][0:1000].find('entre-infideles')
    if pos1 != -1: 
        print '06ReadImap: Message %s' % (num)
        pos2=data[0][1][pos1:].find('Subject')
        pos3=data[0][1][pos1+pos2:].find('Subject: <PUB>')
        pos4=data[0][1][pos1+pos2+pos3:].find('votre profil')
        if pos4 != -1:
            print '06ReadImap: Pos4(votre profil)=%i' % (pos2+pos3+pos4)
            print data[0][1][pos1+pos2+pos3:pos1+pos2+pos3+pos4+12]
            soup=BeautifulSoup(data[0][1])
            for link in soup.find_all('a'):
                print(link.get('href'))
            sys.exit(0)
```

The problem is that it gives me lots of links, of course, all those contained in the email, but they are incomplete and I cannot use them as URL's to 'GET' the pages with any HTLM stuff; it gives that :

```
$ python ./S.py
06ReadImap: Message 8
06ReadImap: Pos4(votre profil)=625
Subject: <PUB> salma311 a =?utf-8?Q?visit=C3=A9?= votre profil
3D"http://fr.supe=
3D"h=
3D"htt=
3D"http://fr.superboxy.me/tracking_unitary/2/111740993/=
3D"http://fr.super=
3D"http://fr.superboxy.me/tracking_unitary/2/111740993/=
...
..
.
```

How can I retrieve the complete URL from the links in the email ?
Many Thanks,
 David

Comment: Sure you want to include the username and password?

Comment: Thank's jonrsharpe; I just checked that it worked as I described it, and I did paste back all the stuff.

Comment: If they were actual credentials, note that they can still be seen in the edit history, so should be invalidated.

Comment: I don't even know how to do that.

Comment: ...change your password?

Comment: Of course I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to undo the Content Transfer Encoding of the message first. This one appears to be in Quoted Printable encoding, which is confusing your HTML parser.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand anything; I just read about "Content Transfer Encoding" once or twice, but I don't know how to deal with it; could you give me a clue ?

Comment: You'll want to use pythons email library to parse your message once you've downloaded it.

Comment: Yes, I found an example here on S/O; Bye

Answer (score 0):

```
        # quoted_printable_decode python
        result = quopri.decodestring(data[0][1])
        #
        soup=BeautifulSoup(result)
        print "\n---------------- Extracting all the URLs found within page 1’s <a> tags :".encode('utf8')
        i=0
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            i=i+1
            print(link.get('href'))
```

Here it goes,
D.